# Replacing commas with dot and dot with commas

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to replace all dots for comma and commas for dots and was wondering what is the best practice for doing this.  If I do it sequentially, then the steps will overwrite each other.

For example:
1,234.56 (after replacing commas) --> 1.234.56 (after replacing dots) --> 1,234,56

Which is obviously not what I want.

One option I guess is splitting on the characters and joining afterwards using the opposite character.  Is there an easier/better way to do this?

Comment: Please give an example to work with.

Comment: What do you mean? An example would simply be changing 1,234.56 to 1.234,56?

Comment: I see... I wasn't sure about how you wanted it to end up... anyway it seems you already got the answer :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use a callback

```
"1,234.56".replace(/[.,]/g, function(x) {
    return x == ',' ? '.' : ',';
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7rf6C/)

If you're going to replace more than two characters, you could create a convenience function using a map to do the replacements

```
function swap(str, swaps) {
    var reg = new RegExp('['+Object.keys(swaps).join('')+']','g');
    return str.replace(reg, function(x) { return swaps[x] });
}

var map = {
    '.':',',
    ',':'.'
}

var result = swap("1,234.56", map); // 1.234,56
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7rf6C/2/)

Comment: +1. But instead of: `/(\.|,)/g`, I'd just use: `/[.,]/g` to eliminate unnecessary alternation and capture group.

Comment: @ridgerunner - sure, but it doesn't really matter

Answer (score 13):

You could do the following:

```
var str = '1,234.56';
var map = {',':'.','.':','};
str = str.replace(/[,.]/g, function(k) {
    return map[k];
});
```

[Working Demo](https://eval.in/171842)

Comment: Nice!  I had been about to suggest a callback along the lines of @adeneo answer, but using an object to match the replacements is much easier to build out.

Comment: That is really nice :D

Comment: If you really want to make it easy to build out, you could create a function that accepts a string and a map and generate the regex dynamically, like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/7rf6C/1/**. If you have to hardcode the regex anyway, a map really doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @adeneo that is alot easier and very nice =)

Comment: +1 for the use of an object literal (which will be more efficient when there are more than two chars in the set to be replaced).

Answer (score 3):

Do it in stages using placeholder text:

```
var foo = '1,234.56';
foo = foo
    .replace(',', '~comma~')
    .replace('.', '~dot~')
    .replace('~comma~', '.')
    .replace('~dot~', ',')
```

Comment: @adeneo's answer is better, actually.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a for loop. Something like:

```
var txt = document.getElementById("txt");
var newStr = "";
for (var i = 0; i < txt.innerHTML.length; i++){
  var char = txt.innerHTML.charAt(i);
    if (char == "."){
      char = ",";   
    }else if (char == ","){
      char = ".";   
    }
    newStr += char;
}
txt.innerHTML = newStr;
```

Here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/AyLQt/1/

Have to say though, @adenoeo's answer is way more slick :D

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can use

```
var value = '1.000.000,55';
var splitValue = value.split('.');
for (var i = 0; i < splitValue.length; i++) {
    var valPart = splitValue[i];
    var newValPart = valPart.replace(',', '.');
    splitValue[i] = newValPart;
}
var newValue = splitValue.join(',');
console.log(newValue);
```